# Re-installing 14.04 LST - impossible

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lvm

I did an on-line "live upgrade" from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LST.

Unfortunately, this resulted in several broken dependencies in some of the programs I use on a daily basis (I am not going to go into the details here..).

So, I thought that the most convenient way to fix things would be to do a fresh 14.04 LST installation on my laptop.

When launching the 14.04 LST installer at boot time (from a USB stick), it tells me that "this computer has no detected OS" ..!  Is the problem related to the fact that I am trying to install 14.04 LST on top of 14.04 LST, or to the fact that I am using LVM (see below).

When choosing the option "do something else", instead of installing 14.04 and "erasing the disk", I face a weird looking partition table which I am not used to .. it has a device mapper related to the logical volume manager (LVM) and it is impossible to set sensible mount points ("/", "/home", etc.) using the ubuntu installer.  So I am stuck.

The partition table of my current 14.04 installation looks like this:

```
sampsa@Sampsa-XPS-13:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006a9fa

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758  1000214527   499856385    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760  1000214527   499856384   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 503.7 GB, 503723327488 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 61240 cylinders, total 983834624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8128 MB, 8128561152 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 988 cylinders, total 15876096 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table


sampsa@Sampsa-XPS-13:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  462G  129G  310G  30% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         3.7G  4.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        755M  1.3M  754M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         3.7G  360K  3.7G   1% /run/shm
none                         100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M  193M   31M  87% /boot
sampsa@Sampsa-XPS-13:~$
```

How should I proceed with the (re-)installation?

Screenshots from the installation [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8s1aqbrlvgvx785/AADmPS_CHciDqz3dtP9AHUfXa).

Answer (score 1):

OK.. It's an ancient bug since 2006 (!)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/43453

Answer (score 0):

My advice is:

1 - Use the Ubuntu CD or other tool (Gparted LiveCD for example) and erase all partitions

Don't mind the weird partitions (as you say), simply erase all of them.

2 - Reboot and try a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I thought as the "last resort" fix.  But the point was that I would like to maintain my /home partition.  It seems that if one uses LVM, upgrading to new versions of ubuntu, but maintaining the /home partition is impossible..  If I only had known ..!

Comment: It is not impossible to reuse the home partition, you can reinstall Ubuntu and leave home untouched